# Run script when new email arrives on gmail with Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, gmail

Is it possible to automatically trigger a Google apps script with gmail when I get a new email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. Instead use a time trigger to check for new mails to process. One way to do it is by using a gmail rule to label the ones you will process. Then only get emails with that label.