# How to have a google app script process incoming email

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like a google app script to run and process newly received email.  I have a script which performs functions that cannot be done using the standard filters/actions in the gmail web ui and I would like to use this function as an action. Is this possible?

Comment: I see this from a few years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754852/run-script-when-new-email-arrives-on-gmail-with-google-apps-script Is this still the case? (i.e. it's not possible except with a time trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible if you use [GMail Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push).

Comment: That seems to use the Watch request. Can that be done from my Google javascript? Any examples available?