# Is it possible to automatically apply a label if another email with same sender has label

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

In Gmail, is it possible to create a filter to automatically applies a label to an email if another email with the same sender already has this label.

For instance, sssuming I have an email from `johndoe@gmail.com` with label `MyLabelA`, can I create a rule that will apply the same label to another email from `johndoe@gmail.com`? Note that the label `MyLabelA` will be applied to hundreds of emails with multiple recipients and I can't use `johndoe@gmail.com` directly to define the filter.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083046/how-to-handle-process-new-gmail-messages-with-the-same-subject-line-and-sende) but I am wondering if there is a way of achieving this without writing a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question:

> I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64083046/how-to-handle-process-new-gmail-messages-with-the-same-subject-line-and-sende) but I am wondering if there is a way of achieving this without writing a script.

Gmail filters are not able to assign a label based on information of other email messages, so no, it's not possible to assign a label using built-in features.

Reference

- [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can check on [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccreate-a-filter):

> 1. Open [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/).
> 2. In the search box at the top, click Show search options.
> 3. Enter your search criteria. If you want to check that your search worked correctly, see what emails show up by clicking Search.
> 4. At the bottom of the search window, click Create filter.
> 5. Choose what you’d like the filter to do.
> 6. Click Create filter.

You can also create a filter based on an email:

> 1. Open Gmail.
> 2. Check the checkbox next to the email you want.
> 3. Click More.
> 4. Click Filter messages like these.
> 5. Enter your filter criteria.
> 6. Click Create filter.